# datetime/timestamp problem with replication from 5.6 to 5.7?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-replication, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I'm replicating from mysql 5.6.33 to 5.7.41. I have a table with a datetime field. If I understand correctly, between 5.6 and 5.7 the decreased the space a datetime field uses because it doesn't store timezone data. (but a timestamp does).

This query works on 5.7 (note the presence of the timezone field):

```
select count(*) from login_activities where date_created < '2023-01-15 04:00:15 -0800';
```

This delete statement does not work:

```
delete from login_activities where date_created < '2023-01-15 04:00:15 -0800'
```

ERROR:

```
Error 'Incorrect datetime value: '2023-01-15 04:00:15 -0800' for column 'date_created' at row 1' on query. Default database: 'sms'. Query: 'delete from login_activities where date_created < '2023-01-15 04:00:15 -0800''
```

How can I get the delete to work in the same way the select works? I've even removed sql_mode entries but still can't get it to work in 5.7

edit:
not sure if this matters, but the error with the delete statement is happining during replication (5.6 -> 5.7), but I'm running the select statement manually. I haven't tried running the delete statement manually because it will through off the replication.

Comment: *because it doesn't store timezone data. (but a timestamp does)* No. TZ data is not stored in all cases. The value is converted to UTC before saving for TIMESTAMP. *This query works on 5.7 ... This delete statement does not work* Execute `SHOW WARNINGS;` immediately after SELECT query. Warning in selection is error in insert/update/delete.

Comment: looks like the warnings are empty.

select count(*) from login_activities where date_created < '2023-01-15 04:00:15'; show warnings;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      760 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: ok, so when I don't include the timezone in the select there is no warning. But when I do include the timezone in the select there is a warning:
mysql> select count(*) from login_activities where date_created < '2023-01-15 04:00:15 -0800'; show warnings;
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                  |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '2023-01-15 04:00:15 -0800' for column 'date_created' at row 1 |

Comment: Syntax failure produces WARNING in SELECT whereas the same syntax failure in INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE produces ERROR.

Comment: when I use str_to_date with the timezone in the date string there are no warnings:
select count(*) from login_activities where date_created <  STR_TO_DATE('2023-01-15 04:00:15 -0800',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s -0800");
but... I think I have to go back to replicating 5.6->5.6 and make some changes in the code.

Comment: *when I use str_to_date with the timezone in the date string there are no warnings* :facepalm: Remove TZ from the pattern. PS. [Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html) - study carefully.

Comment: yeah, i wish i could remove the timezone, but it's an autogenerated string/date in rails that works in 5.6 but not in 5.7. I think I need to go back to replicating 5.6->5.6 and track down areas in the code where it's including the tz in the date.